# Outra forma do UPDATE?

Tags: mysql

Estou fazendo um trabalho de aula Mysql e gostaria de saber outra forma do UPDATE, porque esta não está alterando.

> Atualizar o preço do serviço de todos os animais que receberam banho no pet shop e tiveram valor menor que 15 reais.

---

```
UPDATE `aula_sub_query`.`servico_prestado` 
    SET `preco` = 25.00
    WHERE `cod_SERVICO_PRESTADO` = 1 AND `preco` < 25.00;
```

---

Comment: O ideal nesses casos, é você também postar as suas estruturas de tabelas para que possamos lhe ajudar melhor.

Answer (score 5):

Andrews, assumindo que o código do serviço prestado para Banho no PET SHOP, seja 1, conforme você está utilizando no WHERE, basta corrigir o valor da sua condicional.

Ao invés de utilizar

```
UPDATE aula_sub_query.servico_prestado SET preco = 25.00
WHERE cod_SERVICO_PRESTADO = 1 AND preco < 25.00;
```

Utilize

```
UPDATE aula_sub_query.servico_prestado SET preco = 25.00
WHERE cod_SERVICO_PRESTADO = 1 AND preco < 15;
```